# I keep getting "Revert to template" whenever I set a custom masterpage for one particular page

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, master-page, custom-masterpage

I made 2 master pages. One named "reg_page.master" for all the regular pages, still containing the Quick Launch, and another one named "home_page.master" for the homepage only. The homepage has an app-like menu in the content (I didn't change the top navigation), and this takes the full width of the content. Hence, I wanted the quick launch on this page to be gone. So I had put the code for the Quick Launch from "home_page.master" into a hidden panel, styled that, and now the quick launch is no longer visible. The code is still there (I didn't remove it to prevent errors), but it is just not visible online.

Now, I had set the "reg_page.master" as the default master page, "home_page.master" is a custom master page. On home.aspx I have attached the "home_page.master" as its master page.

When I assign "home_page.master" to home.aspx (my home page), it shows "*The current page has been customized from its template. Revert to template.*" in the browser. And even though the layout is as it should be, as soon as I revert to template it once again shows the Quick Launch. This is not what I want.

**How on earth do I get rid of this message?** I don't want to hide the code since I still want it to be able to show other messages, but I just need a way to prevent this message from showing up. I tried to just change the path to the master page in the home.aspx page itself but that doesn't do it either.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated, I've been looking into this for too long and it is really starting to bug me now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about other messages will be shown or not.
But if u want to hide it using css then try this

```
body #pageStatusBar{height:0px; font-size:0px; padding:0px; border-style:none;}
```

Comment: Well I know that one works, but it will hide other messages. Like when a user wants to edit a document and another user also has that certain document opened, than that div is used to tell the user he/she can't open the document. 
Hence the reason why I wish not to hide it. I simply want to disable only that particular message. :/

Answer (score 0):

The best (and easiest) way that I've found to remove that notice was a workaround [posted on this Consulting blog](http://www.entrancesoftware.com/2013/04/23/sharepoint-consultant-tip-removing-revert-to-template/).

Using SPD, you are basically going to export a copy of the site to your local machine, re-upload it, and behold: the blue info icon is gone (which denotes that the site has deviated from the template). You can then delete the problematic page, and then rename the copy to take place of the old file.

I have also personally confirmed that this works several times.